# Parse error thrown by get_post_meta

Tags: post-meta

in a custom plugin I am developing, I am getting this error as soon as I activate the plugin:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/plugin.php on line 106

I have hunted down the exact line throwing the fatal error:

```
$gallery_pictures_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_image_gallery')[0];
```

It's worth noting that this line works both in local development and on a staging server.

Why is this happening? What is so weird about it?

Comment: this is a php question, not a wordpress one....

Comment: @MarkKaplun Technically, yes. But as the answer by TheDeadMedic below shows, there is a WP-native work-around. So I'd say, let it stand.

Comment: @DougalCampbell, that is a php solution.... by definition wordpress can not overcome differences in language syntax between different php versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and is only available in PHP 5.4+

To support older versions, you need to assign the array, and then access the index:

```
$data = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_image_gallery' );
$gallery_pictures_id = $data[0];
```

Having said that, in your case use the [third argument "single"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
$gallery_pictures_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_image_gallery', true );
```